# mongodb update 1 million records

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

I have a collection with 1 million documents. Each document has an ip field. I have a node function which can return me the country code by passing ip as its param. I was going to get all the records, run my node function, insert the returned country name back to the documents. and update them at once. however, mongodb has a limit on 16M data.

Before

```
{
    _id: xxxxx,
    ip: '207.97.227.239'
}
```

After

```
{
    _id: xxxxx,
    ip: '207.97.227.239',
    country_abbr: 'US'
}
```

my question is how I can safely and quickly update these 1 million records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you will set up the `country_abbr` field depending upon the value of `ip`. So i think you will need an update command that checks for `ip` and sets the value for `country_abbr`. This is how you should do it:

```
db.collection.update (
    {ip : condition_for_ip},
    {$set : {country_abbr : desired_value}},
    {multi : true}
);
```

You will need to run this query multiple times to cover all the countries possible in your collection.

To check if there is some document left in your collection without any value for `country_abbr`, you can run the following query:

```
db.collection.find({'country_abbr' : {$exists : false}});
```

If the above written find query returns any document, you can read the `ip` and see which more countries you need to add.

**Edit after clarification:**

The returning documents is too large and crosses the 16MB limit in your case. So what you do is that you fetch only the `ip` and store them all in a linked list. Then you iterate through the list and using the magical `node` function that you have, you get the correct `country_abbr` value. Lastly you issue a simple update to mongo the way written above.

To generalize my answer for everyone, instead of the function that the person who asked this question has, you can do a manual typing or whatever you want and supply the `country_abbr` value for the update command above.

Comment: basically, I have a node function that returns the country name based on an ip. I was thinking to get all the records and loop through each of the records and insert the return country name back into the document. however, mongodb will only return me 16M data. that is the problem

Comment: that is a solution. I can try

Comment: @well: probably it did because OP accepted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the update method?
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/

Comment: Actually, if I use update method, I need to get all the data first in order to do update, right? however, mongodb only returns you 16M.

Comment: Also, I need to get the date first in order to use the existing ip to get the country name and then update the document